# How to create a Tree like UITableView structure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tree, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have an NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries that looks like this

```
<Blank BlankName="V6" Type="Line" CurrentType="Crypt"/>
<Blank BlankName="T3" Type="Ion" CurrentType="Crypt"/>
<Blank BlankName="HU" Type="Sia" CurrentType="Crypt"/>
<Blank BlankName="HF" Type="Ion" CurrentType="Crypt"/>
<Blank BlankName="HU5" Type="Sia" CurrentType="Crypt"/>
<Blank BlankName="HU6" Type="Sia" CurrentType="Less"/>
<Blank BlankName="V6" Type="Line" CurrentType="Less"/>
<Blank BlankName="V66" Type="Line" CurrentType="Less"/>
```

I am trying to figure out how to place it into a tree like structure to be displayed in a UITableView.

There will be 3 types of information, in this structure

```
Header (unique) - CurrentType
 - Sub Header (unique) - Type
  - Info (multiple items) - BlankName
```

So Using the xml I have as an example the UITableView would look something like this.

```
Crypt
 - Ion
  - T3
  - HF
 - Line
  - V6
 - Sia
  - HU
  - HU5
Less
 - Line
  - V6
  - V66
 - Sia
  - HU6
```

I don't really have any sample code that I have been working on as I really don't know where to start on this, for instance if there is a specific structure suited for storing this type of information or not. I haven't looked into sorting because I have no clue about how it could be stored.

I am still reading and investigating after asking this question.

Comment: just google 'Collapsible Table Structures". You will find ton of them. But do remember to understand the Logic and implementation behind them. there is no fun in simply copying :)

Comment: Awesome, will check them out. Yep I love learning its just with this I have never seen a solution or anything so didnt know where to start. Also the thing being I do not want it to be colapsible I would just like to know how to create that structure I am after.. Header, sub header, info.. hopfully this will help me with that.

Comment: I do have a solution with me. but giving it to you is too easy :D :P ..use dictionary to maintain header + subheader + .. for keys, and on clicking a cell just insert new objects in your cell datasource array by fetching from the subheader array and reload the table with indentation for the newly inserted cells :D ..something along these lines ;)

Comment: I edited my answer above, sound cool thanks for the info.. but I am more intrested in understanding how to independantly sort Headers, Sub Headers and Info into a flat array that I will then use on a tableview.. I will look into collapsing table structures anyway as there might be some info or help in there for me. again thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

To create a flat array - change you parsing code to create an array like this:

```
[ <Dictionary containing Header 1 title, indentation 0>,
  (Dictionary containing Sub-Header 1 title, indentation 1),
  -Dictionary containing Sub-Header-info 1 title, indentation 2-,
  -Dictionary containing Sub-Header-info 1 title, indentation 2-,
  .....
  (Dictionary containing Sub-Header 2 title, indentation 1),
  .....
  <Dictionary containing Header 2 title, indentation 0>,
  .....
  and so on.
]
```

Instead of Dictionary, you can create your own custom object class to hold values of indentation and title and other stuffs. will be easier to use :)
Cheers :)

Comment: oh right.. I toyed with this idea for a little bit... however the one thing I couldnt figure out was alphabetized sorting. any idea if thats possible? thanks for your answer...

Comment: alphabetical sorting on client side will be tricky because I assume you will want to sort the Headers, Sub headers and info-items separately. Better if you do the sorting on Server side in whatever database you are maintaining.

Comment: Yep thats exactly what I was hoping for... If I cant I will just show it as is.. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the easiest way to represent items in a `UITableView` (in my opinion) is with a flat array (or an array of flat arrays if you have multiple sections).

What you need to do is increase the indentation level based on what level of the tree you're in, but you also need the correct order.

It might help to have an object that looks like this:

```
@interface MyObject 

@property NSInteger level;

@property id object;

@end
```

Now, iterate through your XML.  Set the `level` property on this object to the correct depth the object is in the XML, and let `object` be a pointer to the original object.

As you do this, throw all of these objects into an array and make sure you're getting the order right.

Once you've built the array, now just use it with the table view's data source.

For `numberOfRows`, return the array's count.

When you're creating the table view cells, set the indentation level to the `level` property you set in the container object.

Comment: Yea.. I see what your saying but the issue in my mind comes when sorting the three different levels. Header, Sub Header and Info need to all be sorted independantly... I dont know how to achive this in a flat array.

Comment: In addition to `level` and `object`, you can add a reference to `parent`.  Every object with the same `parent` object must come between `parent` and the next object whose `level` is `<=` the parent's `level`.